# Is: [self.window setRootViewController:top]; really needed? (iOS6 autorotation)

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Is: `[self.window setRootViewController:top];` really needed? I am using ECSlidingViewController and can't get it to work with iOS6 autorotation. In ECSlidingViewController class, this is how it adds subview:

```
[self.view addSubview: _topViewController.view];
```

How do i enable autorotation methods, totally stuck!? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to set your window's root view controller, or to add a controller's subview to it.  Unless you're trying to support iOS 3 or earlier, you should do the former.  So in short, yes, `[self.window setRootViewController:top];` is needed.

To enable autorotation for child controllers, you need to use the child view controller methods, like this:

```
[_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_topViewController];
[self.view addSubview: _topViewController.view];
[_topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

You may also need to override `-[shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods]`, but since the default implementation returns `YES` you probably don't.

Comment: So where do i put this Simon, real newbie, in the ECSlidingViewController class, in -(void)setTopViewController:(UIViewController *)theTopViewController ?

Comment: I just want to be able to choose what orientations i have in all my view controllers, but i know you need to set root view controller in delegate, but not sure how to implement with ECSlidingViewController... Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Put the code snippet in wherever you currently have `[self.view addSubview: _topViewController.view];`.

Comment: It seems to only be listening to the very first view controllers rotation methods... How can i overwrite these in the view that's on the top?

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}`

Comment: You need to find the corresponding controller for the view.  What controller is on top?

Comment: You'll also want to check each of the controllers in the stack - if any of them are returning NO, then the ones at the top won't be checked.

Comment: It initially loads a controller called InitialViewController, and everything get adds on top of that, so it only listens to the rotation methods in InitialViewController..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22338/discussion-between-ryan-gittings-and-simon)